# How to set port in WSO2ESB and WSO2 MB

Tags: wso2, qpid, wso2-esb

Am working with WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 and WSO2 MB 2.2.0.

I have made integration between WSO2 ESB and WSO2 MB  by following the below link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB220/Integrating+WSO2+ESB

I have started the MB server successfully with port as shown below

```
[2015-01-19 14:32:20,868]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.cluster.GlobalQueueManager} -  Starting Global Queue Worker for Global Queue : GlobalQueue_9
[Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5675
[2015-01-19 14:32:26,132]  INFO {qpid.message.broker.listening} - [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5675
[Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8675
[2015-01-19 14:32:26,138]  INFO {qpid.message.broker.listening} -  [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8675
[Broker] BRK-1004 : Qpid Broker Ready
```

And when i started ESB server it shows an error as shown below

```
[2015-01-19 14:37:34,275]  INFO - AMQConnection Unable to connect to  broker at tcp://localhost:5672
 org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection
at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport$IoConnectorCreator.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:216)
at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:74)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:120)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnection.java:616)
at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:398)
```

Am not sure but i think there is mismatch in port with which the esb is trying to connect to the broker,Is there any way to change this port an connect successfully to the broker..?

Help me with this.

Comment: What's your port offset for MB?

Comment: Thanks for replay @Abimaran Kugathasan  offset of MB is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, You have 3 as the port offset, Please do the following

Open the `<ESB_HOME>/repository/conf/JNDI.proerties` file and point to the running Message Broker.

Use `carbon` as the virtualhost. Define a queue called `JMSMS`. Comment out the topic as it is not needed. But, in order to avoid getting `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TopicConnectionFactory`  during server startup, point `TopicConnectionFactory` also to the Message Broker.

```
# register some connection factories
# connectionfactory.[jndiname] = [ConnectionURL]
connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5675'
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5675'
# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.JMSMS=JMSMS
queue.StockQuotesQueue = StockQuotesQueue
```

Comment: Hi Abimaran  plz look in to the below link and help me if u have any solution for this     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478909/wso2esb-authentication-service-exception